# axure generate only html code without any thing else

Tags: axure

I'm using Axure (https://www.axure.com/) in collaboration with Graphic Design in order to develop a web site and I wish to know if it is possible to generate from Axure Html code without Axure things.

In others words, I wish to have only Html code in order to see a normal web page:[image: Web page that I see]

Is it possible to remove Axure panel? And can I have only normal web code in order to modify for instance with WebStorm without the Axure code inside?

I search a way in order to have simple page Html that informatics people can modify and for example to insert bootstrap or another things.

Answer (score 1):

While generating HTML you need to check radio button without side bar then you will get only html output without Axure things.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer 
https://www.axure.com/support/reference/viewing-and-sharing-html-output

--------------------AXURE-----

Comment: I have read, but there is not the option in order to generate only Html. I have thought that there is a plug in or another tool in order to have simple Html file that informatics people can modify in a simple way.

Comment: normally is diffuclte to modify it ,   axure is just for mock-up, you can just take others templates

Comment: Do you know others templates for doing them (mock-up and after to modify the code)?

Comment: im sorry i don't know

Comment: Don't worry, thank you very much. I have studied it and I have understand that it is almost impossible to do it. So the best way is to go in another direction for doing it.